# Choose the correct answer

Tags: passive-voice, relative-clauses

His first short story, ...... in 1925, established him as one of the great short story writers worldwide.

(published - was published - which published - is published)

---

My answer: **published** and my book's answer: **was published**. Am I missing something?

Comment: Get a better book. You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the sentence in its current form the correct answer is *published* because of the presence of the comma.

> His first short story, published in 1925, established him as...

Removing the comma could allow you to use *was published*, but also requires other modifications:

> His first short story was published in 1925, which established him as...

Or adding *which* in front of it:

> His first short story, which was published in 1925, established him as...

So to use *was* you also need to add *which*, and that is not given to you as an option, so *was published* cannot be the right answer.

Since 1925 is in the past you cannot use the present tense *is*, which also rules that one out.

You could possibly get away with *which published*:

> His first short story, which published in 1925, established him as...

However I count that as dubious since it implies (to me, anyway) that the book published itself, not that it was published by someone.